# JWT y Refresh Token

Tags: jwt, tokens, auth, refresh

Estoy desarrollando el login de un sistema con Golang.

### LOGIN

Actualmente cuando el usuario se loguea genero dos tokens: el **JWT** que es `stateless` y tiene un tiempo de expiración y un **refresh_token**. A este último lo almaceno en una colección `Tokens` que es un objecto que asocia un token con un usuario.

### REFRESH

Para refrescar el token **JWT**, se pasa el refresh_token y se valida que el usuario que lo envia efectivamente cuente con ese token en la BD.

No estoy seguro si esta es la forma correcta de implementar la autenticacion con JWT y refresh tokens. Se les ocurre una mejor forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Puesto que tu pregunta no contiene dudas de codigo,, puede ser eliminada. Tu duda se resuelve facilmente leyendo articulos referente al tema,

Answer (score 0):

No conozco bien como trabajar con golang. Pero cuando tienes token y refresh_token. Mientras tú token no expire, haces peticiones normalmente con el durante su tiempo de vida.

Ya cuando el token expira, te tocaría enviar el refresh_token, si el tiempo de vida de la sesión aún no expira, se debe devolver un token y refresh_token nuevo, ya que la sesión se debe mantener viva.

Si en cambio ya expiró la sesión, se devuelve que el usuario ya no está autenticado.

Comment: Amigo estoy tratando de implementar este mismo método en angular con node.js. tengo varias dudas: 1) el refreshToken también debe tener un tiempo de expiración? 2) el token no se guarda en la BD y el refreshToken si ? Habría que agregar una columna refreshToken para cada usuario en la BD ?

Comment: en tu storage de informacion de sesion-usuario debes guardar el refreshtoken